# Quantum gates supported by qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming

My question might look a little inappropriate and very basic but I want to know all the quantum gates of qiskit.
The link https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/single-qubit-gates.html#generalU gives a list of some quantum gates but this is not an exhaustive list because there are some more complex gates like **urcy** and **urcz** which I have only recently.
It would be really helpful if someone at least can name and if possible can explain a little about  all the quantum gates which are supported by qiskit.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think qiskit circuit library [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/circuit_library.html) have some of the info you need, this is not an exhaustive list also

Comment: You may use: `for g in Gate.__subclasses__(): print(g.__name__)`

Answer (score 1):

It may not be everything in Qiskit, but to view the most prominently used gates, and to have quick links to each of their forms, functions, and possible modifications, I like to log into my IBMQ account and go to the composer page.  In this drag and drop circuit building interface you can right click on any of the gates and it will provide you with key information along with a link to the qiskit documentation to provide further information about the gate.  It's also nice because you can drop it directly onto a circuit to see the result of the transformation.